# How to group applications used together?

Tags: unity, application-switcher, tmux

I frequently use tmux to split my terminal so that half my screen has vim and the other half is the shell.  This allows me to somewhat "group" vim and the shell together so that whenever I alt-tab to the terminal, I will have half my screen as vim and half my screen as the shell.

I was wondering if there is anyway to reproduce this effect with GUI applications.
i.e. Is there anyway I can group two arbitrary applications such that they always appear with each other.

Say application A and B are "grouped", alt-tabbing to application A (or the the group) will show both application A and B.  Moving application A to another workspace will also move application B with it.

Perhaps something like a tmux for the screen (smux?)...

Comment: I guess this is at least possible with a script and I'm already just waiting for @JacobVlijm to appear and write one of his awesome pieces of code. :D Oh and FYI, there's `terminator`, a terminal emulator that has the ability to split its window into two (four, more...) terminals already built in. You might want to check that out.

Answer (score 0):

Should probably look into a tiling window manager such as i3 or awesome to achieve tmux-like behaviour

(Will add more info to this answer when I have more time to try them)